# How to save the current HTML file with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I write value in inputs and after clicking to a button it shows me in the table. But how I can save the current html file with JavaScript after adding new values to the table??? Pls help

Comment: Please post the code samples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try using window.localStorage to set and get values on the user's device.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: yes I already used them but there i can only set one value

Comment: you could store the data in an array then use `JSON.stringify` to turn it into a string, which you could store in LS.

the reverse is possible, just `JSON.parse` the data in LS to get back an array

Comment: LS is short for localStorage, which can be used to store data locally in a key-value pairs

Answer (score -1):

You need to store them in a database.

You need to build a backend to handle that.

and then fetch data from the backend to your html / js project.

Learn about Http requests to do these.

Comment: No unfortunately I don't know backend yet. Thanks for the advice